# algorithms, np, colorability

Tags: algorithms

I have a question that states as follows:

```
Give an argument that a graph is 3-colorable if and only if the input 3sat instance is satisfiable.
```

I don't particularly want the answer, What I would really like is help understanding what this is asking for?

Any help would be appreciated though, thank you!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526302/algorithm-np-completeness-3-colorability) post on the main SO site from a couple hours ago seems to touch on something similar.

Comment: I checked out that question, it seems to fit what im asking but I dont understand what this question is asking... "Give an argument" so would an argument be like "A graph is 3-colorable if and only if teh input 3sat instance is satisfiable because if it was not, then the nodes couldnt connect due to the sameness of adjacent colors"??

Comment: I think part of the confusion might be stemming from your question missing a little context. The question typically deals with the 3-colorability of a graph that is constructed from a 3-SAT instance, not just any graph.

Comment: Ok so lets pretend that a graph is given that has been found from a graph constructed from a 3-SAT instance, what would an argument be? Proving that its true? or maybe showing that it is false if its 3-SAT instance doesn't work? I might just be missing a main component...

Comment: Yeah, the basic idea would be to show that the statement is true (assuming we're talking about these constructed graphs).